# How to increase batch size of kafka consumer batch

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am using kafka consumer `eachBatch: async ({ })`

to fetch messages from kafka because our system has to process millions of messages per day and sync the same to Big Query

How can I increase batch size to 100 messages?

Comment: Why 100? `max.poll.records` Kafka config defaults to 500 records already

Comment: to change max.poll.records in which configuration file? please tell me the location of configuration file.

Comment: There's no file. It's a consumer client property set around the same place as bootstrap servers and group id, for example

Comment: Maybe KafkaJS client doesn't support this though https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/420 but node-librdkafka would